# Python can't find local module

Tags: python, importerror

I have a folder structure like this:

```
setup.py
core/
    __init__.py
    interpreter.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_ingest.py
```

If I try to import `core` in `test_ingest.py` and run it, I get an `ImportError` saying that the `core` module can't be found. However, I can import `core` in `setup.py` without an issue. My IDE doesn't freak out, so why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you `import` your package, Python searches the directories on `sys.path` until it finds one of these: a file called "core.py", or a directory called "core" containing a file called `__init__.py`. Python then [imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) your [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package).

You are able to successfully `import core` from `setup.py` because the path to the `core` directory is found in `sys.path`.  You can see this yourself by running this snippet from your file:

```
import sys

for line in sys.path:
     print line
```

If you want to import `core` from a different file in your folder structure, you can append the path to the directory where `core` is found to `sys.path` in your file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module")
```

Comment: I've seen this solution quite frequently; in `test_ingest.py`, I have `sys.path.append("/Users/apizzimenti/Desktop/simple-engine-core/core")`. After this, I run `import core`, and an ImportError still follows. If I print the lines in `sys.path` after appending the path to the module, the path appears there. Even so, I get an ImportError.

Comment: You want `sys.path.append("/Users/apizzimenti/Desktop/simple-engine-core/")` instead.  You want to append the path to the directory in which `core` is found, not the path to the module itself.

Comment: That works. Thank you! Now, for me to import `core` into other files in the `tests` module, do I have to append that path in every file?

Comment: My pleasure!  You could do that if you wanted to; alternatively, you could add the path to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472436/

Comment: I am on a mac and that answer mainly pertains to windows, but I added the path to the PYTHONPATH env variable and it all works out. Thank you for your help :) you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Haha!  Thank you very much; it's my pleasure.  Good luck!