# import mlpack fails in python

Tags: python, mlpack

I am trying to use mlpack in python scripts. I just installed the mlpack package from source into my directory `/home/glassjawed/local/` and

```
glassjawed@Y9Acer:~$ ls local/lib | grep mlpack
libmlpack.so
libmlpack.so.3
libmlpack.so.3.0

glassjawed@Y9Acer:~$ ls local/include/mlpack/bindings/python
get_arma_type.hpp        print_defn.hpp
get_cython_type.hpp      print_doc_functions.hpp
get_numpy_type_char.hpp  print_doc_functions_impl.hpp
get_numpy_type.hpp       print_doc.hpp
get_param.hpp            print_input_processing.hpp
get_printable_param.hpp  print_output_processing.hpp
get_python_type.hpp      print_pyx.hpp
import_decl.hpp          py_option.hpp
mlpack                   strip_type.hpp
print_class_defn.hpp
```

So mlpack is clearly installed. HOWEVER, I can't seem to run this in python because I get a module not found error.

```
glassjawed@Y9Acer:~$ python
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 21 2018, 03:09:43) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>> import mlpack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlpack'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I tried everything.
`

Comment: How is python to know to look your mlpack module in your local directory? Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135119/python-cant-find-local-module

Comment: You should be able to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when you start Python to include your `local/lib` directory and I think this will solve the issue.